# EPPlus - Cannot find column 10

Tags: epplus

I have an application where user uploads excel ( 2007 or higher ) file, this file gets parsed, and content is stored in Database. I'm reading content from Excel using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Here's the code snippet

```
foreach (var worksheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
                        {
                            for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
                            {
                                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();

                                for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
                                {
                                    newRow[j - 1] = worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
                                }

                                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                            }
                        }
```

When value of j reaches to 11, I got following exception **Cannot find column 10**. But I did check the file, it actually has column index 10. I've put a breakpoint, watch the value of column 9, and it is exactly the same value before column 10.

So anybody can help me out ? What the problem really is ?

I checked up the API, EPPlus lib actually has an index property Cells, which accepts as a second argument the index of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the exception is from "worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value" and not from "newRow[j - 1]"? Your loop counter "j" is 11 yet the exception indicates "Cannot find column 10" which does match the "[j-1]" indexer on your newRow.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't had appropriate number of columns in my DataTable Columns collection. Thanks for pointing that out.